# Compiling OpenSSL in Windows - generated LIB uses wrong name for DLL files

Tags: c++, compilation, openssl, static-libraries, dynamic-library

I'm trying to compile OpenSSL 1.1.1d version locally.

Due to my project, I need to edit **windows-makefile.tmp** under Configuration folder.
I have to prepend the file extensions like so:

```
 our $objext = $target{obj_extension} || "_vc10.obj";
 our $resext = $target{res_extension} || "_vc10.res";
 our $depext = $target{dep_extension} || "_vc10.d";
 our $exeext = $target{exe_extension} || "_vc10.exe";
 our $libext = $target{lib_extension} || "_vc10.lib";
 our $shlibext = $target{shared_extension} || "_vc10.dll";
```

Compilation is finished successfully, no problems.
But I had errors whenever my program uses libcrypto.
Upon inspection of the generated libcrypto-1_1_vc10.lib, I found out that the lib uses **.dll** with name

`libcrypto-1_1.dll`

instead of the prepended

`libcrypto-1_1_vc10.dll`

I expected the latter will be used since, well, this will be the generated .dll file.
I also tried to prepend the following file extensions, but it didn't do much.

```
 our $shlibextimport = $target{shared_import_extension} || ".lib";
 our $dsoext = $target{dso_extension} || ".dll";
```

I skimmed through the generated Makefile but I don't see much that will generated only **libcrypto-1_1.dll** (Or probably I'm not yet familiar on how Makefile works).

Due to my project, I need to keep the **_vc10** on the file names.

Are there other parts of the **windows-makefile.tmp** or other configuration that I need to edit?
Any clues will be beneficial. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation and thanks to the notes of my colleagues, I was able to resolve this issue.

This maybe a hackish way to resolve this but this is how I fixed my issue.

In

```
util/mkdef.pl
```

there is a function

```
sub print_def_file
{
...
my $libname = $name;
...
```

Update the $libname value to your desired libname referenced by libcrypto.lib or libssl.lib

ex:

```
my $libname = $name . "_vc10";
```

PS: If there are other ways to resolve this, please let me know.